# Reference Error :"details is not defined, EJS"

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, ejs

I don't know why this error is continuously occurring I already declare the value in details but still it's continuously giving me error of "details not define", the purpose of this code is to get the data from mongodb compass database and display it. But when ever I open the page it gives me that error. I am a beginner, so please let it go any problem in question I already tried my best to solve it but unable to do so.

**fetch.js**

```js
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyparser = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://mangement:killerloui@cluster0.qffmthl.mongodb.net/newcollection", {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get("/index", function(req, res) {
    res.render("index");
});
const contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    salary: String,
    idno: String,
    gender: String,
    date: String,
});
const Contact = mongoose.model("Contact", contactSchema);
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("index", {
        details: null
    })
})
app.get("/getdetails", function(req, res) {
    Contact.find({}, function(err, allDetails) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("index", {
                details: allDetails
            })
        }
    })
})
app.listen(3000, "localhost", function() {
    console.log("server has started");
})
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    #heading{
        margin-left: 39%;
    }
    table {
    margin-left: 29%;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid;
}
th{
    border: 2px solid black;
}
td{
    border: 2px solid black;
}


</style>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="/getdetails">Get Details</a>
        </div>
        <hr>
        
        <% if(details!=null) { %>
        <h2 id="heading">REGISTER RECORDS</h2>
        <table >
        <tr>
            <th id="n1">Name</th>
            <th id="n2">Salary </th>
            <th id="n3">ID-NO</th>
            <th id="n4">Gender</th>
            <th id="n5">DATE JOIN</th>
          
        </tr>
        <% details.forEach(function(item){ %>
        <tr id="fix" >
            <td><%= item.name%></td>
            <td><%= item.salary %></td>
            <td><%= item.idno%></td>
            <td><%= item.gender%></td>
            <td ><%= item.date%></td>
            
        
        </tr>
        <% }) %>
        </table>
        <% } %>
       
        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
<% if(details!=null) { %>
```

To this:

```
<% if( typeof(details) =="undefined") { %>
```

The problem is that your line `details!=null` looks up the value of `details`, but you never declared it in your ejs file. `typeof` is a good way to check if values were ever declared and see what their values are.

Comment: problem is that I got another error on next line.

Comment: @SYEDSAADALI What error?

Comment: <% details.forEach(function(item){ %>.....on this code its again generating error of details not define instead of I again change it with typeof